# Confusing flag detail

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flags, profile-page, flag-history

When I see the flagging history in a user profile it's pretty confusing, the reason being:

> [image]

Marked as point 1 and 2 it shows what flags were deemed helpful. Why does it show it at both places? Why not at only one place and why is the calculation for 53 flags total `1  + 50 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 3 = 61`?

But if I remove section 2 then it's 53. What is the meaning/reason to show it in two places?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spam flags are counted separately (for some reason; possibly because some of them are resolved automatically).

Of your 53 other flags, 50 has been marked helpful by a moderator, one has been rejected (declined), and one was counter flagged by another user (disputed). The last one isn't decided yet. That looks like 50+3, which is the total.

Flags on comments are not counted with the others, as comments are not considered very important.

Comment: per my recent experience, helpful comment flags count for badges: I've got _Marshal_ at Programmers having non-comments flags under 500 (comments flags made the sum over 500)

Comment: Ok, I got my Marshal badge based on flag weight, where I believe the comment flags didn't count. Things change!