# Profile flag stats are misleading

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, flag-history

On your main profile/dashboard, there is a "helpful flag" stat with a number (in my case, 86):

[image]

If you click on the number, you are taken to your flagging history with more stats which say that my number of flags "deemed helpful" is really 79, not 86 as the main profile suggests.

[image]

Not to mention that the use of the term "moderator attention flags" is confusing.. There is a separate option for "moderator attention" when flagging, but "moderator attention flags" in the history seemingly refers to total number of flags..

Can these terms and numbers be clarified and made more consistent?

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of another question?

Comment: @Cupcake yup, 1.8k more rep and you can aid in closing. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not a bug, it is [by-design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144092/confusing-flag-detail). The **helpful flags** count (86) on your profile page is the sum of all your flags which were **deemed helpful** (79+4+3).

[image]

In your case, the number of helpful flags and total moderator attention flags raised by you happen to be the same (coincidence). 3 waiting for review + 79 helpful + 2 declined + 2 disputed = 86 moderator attention flags.

Just in case you are wondering, [Why does flagging history display “spam flag count” separately](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98931/why-does-flagging-history-display-spam-flag-count-separately).